# Chakra-UI Rendering Tabs Based On LocalStorage Setting

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I can't seem to get the tab to render as active if a condition is met based on localStorage settings. Here is what I have:

```js
<TabList id="my-view-menu" direction="row" spacing={4}>
  <Tab
    colorScheme="#000"
    fontSize="sm"
    variant="link"
    onClick={(e) => handleDefaultView(e)}
    isSelected={localStorage.getItem('view') === 'default' ? true : false}
  >
    Default
  </Tab>

  <Tab
    colorScheme="#000"
    fontSize="sm"
    variant="link"
    onClick={(e) => handleMyView(e)}
    isSelected={localStorage.getItem('view') === 'myView' ? true : false}
  >
    My View
  </Tab>
</TabList>;
```

Comment: Could try using just the condition like this `isSelected={localStorage.getItem('view') === 'default'}`

Comment: Good idea, but that didn't work either..

Comment: Could you confirm that `localStorage.getItem` is returning that expected value

Comment: Yes, when I alert() the local storage value through the click handler, I can see each value when I click the relevant tab.

Comment: What happens when you hardcode `true` in one of the tabs? Does that Tab get selected?

Comment: interesting - hardcoding true and false don't seem to do anything here... On either tab.

Comment: I'm going to have to use some kind of selector based on the ```aria-selected``` attribute: ```const handleDefaultView = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('view', 'default');
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
    tabs[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', true);
    tabs[1].setAttribute('aria-selected', false);
  };```

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. The documentation specified `isSelected` [as props for Tab](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/disclosure/tabs#tab-props)

Comment: `aria-selected` is for screenreaders accessibility

Comment: `isSelected={localStorage.getItem('view') === 'default' ? 'true' : 'false'}`